# Get A single Record/Document from Firebase Firestore Using Async Await

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I am trying to read a document from firestore using the documents ID and I do not want to use the .then() syntax in the firebase documentation. I want to sue Async await but I get an error of
Cannot read property data of undefined. Below is my code

```js
export const getOneJobById = async jobId => {
  try {
    const snapShot = await db.collection('jobs').doc(jobId).get();
    return snapShot.doc.data();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};
```

Help me understand where I am going wrong

Comment: Hello, @Dharmaraj I saw your answer immediately after you posted it and it worked.  I then Clicked on accept but StackOverflow notified me I can only accept an answer after 11 mins and I forgot to get back and accept it later. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no property `doc` on a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot). You need to use `.data()` on `snapShot` itself.

```
export const getOneJobById = async jobId => {
  try {
    const snapShot = await db.collection('jobs').doc(jobId).get();
    return snapShot.data();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
};
```

---

If you are fetching multiple documents i.e. using `get()` method on a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference) which returns a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) then you access `.docs` property of the query snapshot and use `data()` method on each of them individually as shown below:

```js
const querySnapshot= await db.collection('jobs').get();
console.log(querySnapshot.docs.map(d => d.data()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const totalQuestionsByChapterDocRef = firestore
        .collection('totalNoOfQuestions')
        .doc('byChapter');

let totalsByChapter = (await totalQuestionsByChapterDocRef.get()).data();
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing! If you find time please consider editing an explanation into the answer as it's recommended to [explain entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421) on StackOverflow.